# why i am getting error while passing timestamp?

Tags: reactjs

This is the code =>

```
<div className="post__top"> 
  <p>{new Date(timestamp?.toDate()).toUTCString()}</p>
</div>
```

This is the error

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (62:24)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|       columnNumber: 21
|     }
>   }, new Date(timestamp?.toDate()).toUTCString()))), /*#__PURE__*/React.create
Element("div", {
|     className: "post__bottom",
|     __self: _this,
```

Comment: `timestamp?.toDate()` how is it suppsed to not give any err ?

Comment: @aXuser264 that's a valid syntax called [`optional chaining`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Comment: wow thats cool, thanks for telling i didn't know, sorry?

Comment: what is the correct way of passing?

Comment: @SanathBillava does it work without  `optional chaining` ?

Comment: Seems like you haven't configured webpack correctly. Do you use create-react-app?

Comment: no i'm not getting a propper way to add timestamp, if that line works im able to fetch data from firebase db.

Comment: @Tracer69 yea i used create-react-app only

Comment: "react-scripts": "^2.1.8" this is script version im using, because the current script version is not supported to my pc, is that a probelm?

Comment: Can you try without using optional chaining? Seems like your configuration doesn't consider the babel plugin for optional chaining.

Comment: @YashJoshi sure but can u modify that code and send me please.. im quite weak in conditional statements

Comment: i have used create-react-app to start project but not npx create-react-app, is that a problem?

Comment: You can check the docs on how to do conditional rendering. Here: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: {new Date(timestamp ? timestamp.toDate().toUTCString() : null)} is that correct?